# Intents keep coming back null

Tags: java, android

So Im making a simple organization app and once I getIntent() and set variables to whatever i used .putExtra() on and it just wont transmit the data between views, could it be that I copied the code from a different app I've made and adapted it or what? because when I do getStringExtra
it comes up as null (which i've tested by setting some buttons text to the getStringExtra and it shows up blank)and doesnt have a value. Even though everything should be correct, can someone just look this over please and tell me whats up?

code from main activity

```
  @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
   if(test==1){
        Intent itemCreate = getIntent();
        itemName = itemCreate.getStringExtra(CreateItem.NAME_TEXT);
        itemLocation = itemCreate.getStringExtra(CreateItem.LOCATION_TEXT);
        itemDesc = itemCreate.getStringExtra(CreateItem.DESC_TEXT);
        items.add(new Item(itemName, itemLocation, itemDesc));
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
       // itemNames.add(items.get(items.size()-1).getName());
        addItem.setText(itemName);
       toast.show();
       if(items!=null) {
           lv.setAdapter(adapter);
       }                //toast.show();
    }
}
```

code from sending activity

```
public void openMainActivity() {
    editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.itemNameText);
    editLoc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.itemLocationText);
    editDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.itemPriceText);
    String name = editName.getText().toString();
    String location = editLoc.getText().toString();
    String desc = editDesc.getText().toString();
    Intent itemCreate = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    itemCreate.putExtra(NAME_TEXT, name);
    itemCreate.putExtra(LOCATION_TEXT, location);
    itemCreate.putExtra(DESC_TEXT, desc);
    itemCreate.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(itemCreate);
}
```

Comment: Hi Mikolo welcome to SO, may I know why you are calling getIntent() in onResume() instead of onCreate()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62183269/9164071

Comment: becaue then information that is sent from another view won't be avalible until that second view runs itself,

Answer (score 0):

In the receiving activity have you tried as follows:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
   if(test==1){
        Intent itemCreate = getIntent();

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        if (bundle != null) {
            itemName = itemCreate.getString(CreateItem.NAME_TEXT);
            itemLocation = itemCreate.getString(CreateItem.LOCATION_TEXT);
            itemDesc = itemCreate.getString(CreateItem.DESC_TEXT);
            items.add(new Item(itemName, itemLocation, itemDesc));
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
            // itemNames.add(items.get(items.size()-1).getName());
            addItem.setText(itemName);
            toast.show();
        }

       if(items!=null) {
           lv.setAdapter(adapter);
       }                //toast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes but getString isnt a fuction, I dont know why but its red

Comment: but when ran with the bundle test, the bundle comes up null

Comment: it may help to try creating the bundle and setting the extras on that first, then adding the bundle to the intent maybe? Unsure why it isn't working for you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
   For checking if your string in being received or not, you can use Logcat:

```
////add this on receiving activity, in Logcat search using the key "aaaaaa"
  ////if you received it, it will show you the received text in logcat .
    String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("NAME_TEXT");
    Log.i("aaaaaaa",s);

/////put the key under double quotation/////
public void openMainActivity() {
    editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.itemNameText);
    editLoc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.itemLocationText);
    editDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.itemPriceText);
    String name = editName.getText().toString();
    String location = editLoc.getText().toString();
    String desc = editDesc.getText().toString();
    Intent itemCreate = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    itemCreate.putExtra("NAME_TEXT", name);
    itemCreate.putExtra("LOCATION_TEXT", location);
    itemCreate.putExtra("DESC_TEXT", desc);
    itemCreate.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(itemCreate);
}
```

in receiving activity:  make sure that getStringExtra does not get null value, you can use the getIntent() method directly.

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
   if(test==1){
        itemName = getIntent().getStringExtra("NAME_TEXT");
        itemLocation = getIntent().getStringExtra("LOCATION_TEXT");
        itemDesc = getIntent().getStringExtra("DESC_TEXT");
        items.add(new Item(itemName, itemLocation, itemDesc));
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
       // itemNames.add(items.get(items.size()-1).getName());
        addItem.setText(itemName);
       toast.show();
       if(items!=null) {
           lv.setAdapter(adapter);
       }                //toast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah even that doesn't work, I've had this code work before I think ill start from scratch

Comment: @MikoloSmito, okay you can do that,  but did you check whether you are receiving the message passed in put extra fron sending acivity using  logcat?